# Brownie with Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: brownie

I am trying to use brownie with jupyter notebook. But seems like I am unable to import contracts 'cannot import name 'contractname' from 'brownie.network' (/path/anaconda3/envs/ethereum/lib/python3.9/site-packages/brownie/network/**init**.py)'

Of course it works fine if I have a python script and execute with brownie run scriptname.

Anybody has done this?

Answer (score 0):

Did figure this out.

You merely import 'from brownie import network, accounts,project, config' and then you can instantiate the contract through 'contract = active_project._containers['<_contract_class_name>'].at("<_address>")'